# Difference between multimap and unordered_multimap in c++?

Tags: c++, data-structures, stl, c++14

I have come across these 2 variation of multimap, which one should i use? (when and why). how they are implemented internally?

Comment: The question asked what the two maps are, not the complexities

Comment: I am asking actual difference, also how they are implemented internally in STL(either as BST or hashmap).

Comment: ordered maps are BST (red-black typically) while unordered maps are typical hashmaps. Maps store unique key value pair whereas multimaps have duplicate keys. Usually in such case the value is a collection or list. The link provides a description regarding their complexities.